# :selected values are resetting in page submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Selected values from dropdown are resetting in page submit.here is the code am using

```
<%=select_tag 'num_id', options_for_select(@numbers.collect{ |t| [t.firstno]}),:prompt => "Select"%>
```

How can we set the selected value inside a select_tag in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass another parameter to `options_for_select` to set the selected option

```
<%= select_tag 'num_id', options_for_select(@numbers.map(&:firstno), params[:num_id]), prompt: 'Select' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**select_tag selected value -**

```
options_for_select(@options, @selected_val)
```

Example:

```
 options_for_select(1..8, 5)  # creates options from range 1..8, with 5 as selected by default.
```